# How do I center the paper with the cards inside

Tags: reactjs

I have a view like below. What I want to do is put the cards inside the paper and place the paper in the middle of the screen. How can I do that?
https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-meninsky-etoctt?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Comment: Do you want the cards (aka `canvas` elements) side by side inside the paper?

Comment: No, I'm trying to capture the following view:  https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi0.wp.com%2Fcodemyui.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F05%2Fcss-only-credit-card-payment-ui.gif%3Ffit%3D880%252C440%26ssl%3D1&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcodemyui.com%2Fcss-credit-card-payment-ui%2F&tbnid=V04ZmaL1Z8mK6M&vet=12ahUKEwiisNWFjav5AhVlnf0HHS3PCSUQMygEegUIARDOAQ..i&docid=Ku_Gl1JcAby-mM&w=880&h=440&q=card%20payment%20ui%20&ved=2ahUKEwiisNWFjav5AhVlnf0HHS3PCSUQMygEegUIARDOAQ

Comment: Take a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-elion-7fhc07?file=/src/App.js) is this what you want to achieve? (ps. made paper background red to debug purposes)

Comment: Almost like that. Thank you.